# Why always have error "cannot not read property 'logged' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Below is my app.js code

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cookieSession = require('cookie-session');
var session = require('express-session');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: "HelloExpressSESSION",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

Here is my routes/index.js file

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var user = require('./user');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'My Blog' });
});


router.get('/signin', user.signin);
module.exports = router;
```

and this is my routes/user.js file

```
exports.signin = function(req, res){
  if(req.session.logined){
    res.redirect('/');
    return;
  }
  res.render('users/register');
}
```

When I try to go to localhost:3000/signin page, I always have error like below from user.js file

```
cannot not read property 'logined' of undefined
```

Is anything wrong with my code?

Comment: 'logged' is nowhere in your code. where exactly is this error coming from?

Comment: Nothing seems to be obvious, is that the entire user.js file? And what line is it pointing to if it is the whole file...?

Comment: Sorry, is logined not  logged in user.js

Comment: Then that means that `req.session` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I fixed it but I don't know why.

I put

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
```

after

```
app.use(cookieSession({
    secret: "HelloExpressSESSION",
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

then everything works.
Anyone can explain?